# Как кликнуть на дату в календаре?

Tags: python-3.x, selenium-webdriver

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
<form name="applicantBooking2" id="applicantBooking2" action="appointment.php" method="post" onSubmit="return validateFrm();">
                <tr id="app_date_tr" height="30">
                    <td width="20%" class="styleBlack" style="padding-left:10px;">
                        Appointment Date: <span style="color:#F00">*</span>
                    </td>
                    <td colspan="2">
                    <input type="text" readonly class="form-control-input app_date validate" style="width: 260px;" id="app_date" name="app_date" placeholder="YYYY-MM-DD" onchange="this.form.submit();showLoader();" value="2023-05-25">
                    </td>
                </tr>
```

Здравствуйте,помогите пожалуйста нажать на дату,pyautogui не подходит,вставка даты тоже не помогла.Изначально value=""